# Java retrieve saved wifi keys and locations from Google Account

Tags: java, google-api, google-play-services

Is there any way to retrieve my saved wifi keys from my google account or the saved locations which are saved for optimize google location service?

It would be helpful, if somebody know where the data is stored on google, I think they all are stored on google cloud but I don't know how I can access them.

Comment: I think you can try to use the `Google drive` which is associated with google account, save the date with it, and then retrieve it when you needed. Also there is a api for username and password called `Smart Lock for Passwords on Android`, you can check out here:https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Do I have to enter the key manually? I'm looking for the keys which google (android) automatically saves on there server. On Android it's called Backup and Rest, when you wipe your phone and connect to your google account again all keys will be restored.